# Calculate integral with unusual integrator

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to compute the following integral: $$\int_{X_{n-k:n}}^{\infty}xd\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\left(\frac{X_{n-k:n}}{x}\right)^\frac{1}{\hat{\gamma}}\right)$$

However I have no clue how to cope with any other integrator than just $dx$. Any help or some reference to the needed theory would be appreciated.

Given is some unknown distribution $F$, I need to find its expected value. Since I do not know the underlying distribution the first part is estimated by the empirical distribution function $F_n(x)$. The tail of the distribution (starting at $X_{n-k:n}$) is estimated by $1-\frac{k}{n}\left(\frac{X_{n-k:n}}{x}\right)^\frac{1}{\hat{\gamma}}$. So $E[X]$ is estimated by:

$$E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{X_{n-k:n}}xdF_n(x) + \int_{X_{n-k:n}}^\infty xd\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\left(\frac{X_{n-k:n}}{x}\right)^\frac{1}{\hat{\gamma}}\right)$$

Furthermore it is given that $\hat{\gamma}<1$. I need to find a lower upper bound for $\hat{\gamma}$ for which the expected value exists. Since the first integral doesn't contain $\hat{\gamma}$ and it is finite, this is equivalent to finding those $\hat{\gamma}$ for which the second integral is finite.

The next step that is given is:

$$\int_{X_{n-k:n}}^{\infty}xd\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\left(\frac{X_{n-k:n}}{x}\right)^\frac{1}{\hat{\gamma}}\right)=\frac{k}{n}\frac{1}{\hat{\gamma}}X_{n-k:n}^{\frac{1}{\hat{\gamma}}}\int_{X_n-k:n}^\infty x^{\frac{-1}{\hat{\gamma}}}dx$$

Comment: Can be a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral.

Comment: As the previous commenter pointed out, could this be a Riemann–Stieltjes integral? Have you covered that yet or is it in your textbook?

Comment: Can you please provide more context?